# Invoking Common Lisp macros systematically with varying expressions

Tags: function, macros, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I am learning Common Lisp (SBCL). 
I want to create a facility to invoke two (or more) macros with several similar expressions that differ only in some parameters.

I would like to define the base of the expression, then modify it with the parameters I supply. For this a lambda function definition came to mind.

As far as I know, there is no analogue to `funcall` for macros, so I've also wrapped the macros in lambdas.

I feel like I'm overcomplicating with with all these `lambda`-s and `funcall`-s. Is there a more elegant way?

The macros are from an external lib, so I'd prefer not to modify them. 
 (Specifically, the fiveam testing library's `finishes` and `signals`.)

Here is a sample code:

```cl
(defmacro macro1 (body) ())
(defmacro macro2 (body) ())

(defun check-expr-with-args (do-m func args)
  (dolist (arg args)
    (format t "~a " arg)
    (funcall do-m (lambda () (funcall func arg)))))

(let ((test-expr 
        #'(lambda (val) (format t "~a" val)))
      (cases (list
               (list #'(lambda (func) ( macro1 (funcall func))) 
                     (list 1 2 3 4 5))
               (list #'(lambda (func) ( macro2 (funcall func)))
                     (list -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9)))))
  (dolist (c cases)
    (check-expr-with-args (first c) test-expr (second c))))
```

Originally I've tried to pass the macro names to my `check-expr-with-args` function, and the expressions in quoted form, relying on lexical scoping for the parameter insertion. That didn't work out.

Comment: Use `MACRO-FUNCTION` to get the underlying function that implements the macro, you can call this with `FUNCALL`. Or you can use `MACROEXPAND` or `MACROEXPAND-1`.

Comment: If you're solving some specific problem with `finishes` and `signals`, could you describe what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Note that you don't need to write `#'` in front of lambda

Comment: @MartinPůda I want to test a function with multiple sets of parameters, in cases when it should finish, and in cases when it should signal a condition. But I'm also interested in a general solution to this kind of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can write a wrapper macro that produces code that invokes `macro1` (and `macro2`). For example here I'm defining `m1` that takes (i) a test expression and (ii) an expression that is expected to evaluates at runtime to a list of values.

```
(defmacro m1 (test-expr input-expr)
  (let ((arg (gensym)))
    `(dolist (,arg ,input-expr)
       (macro1 ,test-expr ,arg))))
```

Both `test-expr` and `input-expr` are injected in a `dolist` expression, which binds a variable named `arg`. Here `arg` is a fresh symbol introduced with `gensym`, to avoid accidentally shadowing a variable or symbol-macro possibly used in `test-expr`.

For example:

```
(m1 (some-test-p) (list 1 2 3 4))
```

The above expands as:

```
(DOLIST (#:G1909 (LIST 1 2 3 4)) 
  (MACRO1 (SOME-TEST-P) #:G1909))
```

The resulting expression contains `MACRO1`, which will also be expanded. But it is now wrapped in an expression that iterates over some list computed at runtime. Here, it is a constant but you could replace it with any other expression.

In conclusion, it is often best to combine macros at the macro level, by expanding your own macros into other ones.

Answer (score 2):

> *I want to create a facility to invoke two (or more) macros*

```
(defmacro invoke-macros (macro-forms)
  `(progn ,@macro-forms))
```

> *with several similar expressions that differ only in some parameters.*

```
(defmacro invoke-macros (macro-names &rest macro-arguments)
  `(progn ,@(loop for m in macro-names
                  appending (loop for a in macro-arguments
                                  collecting `(,m ,@a)))))
```

Check:

```
[1]> (macroexpand '(invoke-macros (m1 m2) (a b c) (d e f)))
(PROGN (M1 A B C) (M1 D E F) (M2 A B C) (M2 D E F)) ;
T
```

Of course, this works with any operators, including functions, not only macros; we should call this `invoke-operators`. Or some better name reflecting that we are creating a cartesian product from operators and argument syntax.

If we need the returned values, we can change `progn` to `list`. Or possibly `values` if the number of combinations isn't expected to be large.

If this had to be a function:

```
(defun invoke-ops (op-names &rest op-arguments)
  (loop for o in op-names
            appending (loop for a in op-arguments
                            collecting (eval `(,o ,@a)))))
```

Check:

```
[1]> (invoke-ops '(list +) '(1 2) '(10 20))
((1 2) (10 20) 3 30)
```

Since `invoke-ops` is now a function, we have to quote the arguments.

There is no `funcall` for macros. If you gain access to the expander function of a macro, then there is a funcall, but all it does is perform the code transformation; it won't invoke the macro.

The only ways to invoke the code generated by a macro are: you can `eval` the code, or you can `compile` the code and `funcall` it. The latter approach requires a function, so you place the code into a `lambda` expression first:

```
(funcall (compile nil `(lambda () ,code-output-by-macro)))
```

The `nil` argument of `compile` is the function name; we are telling `compile` that we are not dealing with a named function definition. We supply the code in the second argument. In some Common Lisp implementations, there is no evaluator; the `eval` function does something similar to:

```
(defun eval (code)
  (funcall (compile nil `(lambda () ,code))))
```